# Only echo integers

Tags: php, variables

Is there a way in PHP to only echo the integers from a variable?

For example say I had this piece of code:

```
$variable = "something123";
```

How would I echo out only the "123"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a regular expression for this.

```
preg_match('/\d+/', $variable, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

The `$match` variable is filled with the first numerical part of the string you pass to the `preg_match` function.

`\d+` means "1 or more digits"

Answer (score 1):

```
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','', $variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex and replace everything that isn't a number by an empty string, thus leaving only numbers:

```
<?php
    $variable = 'something123';
    $numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $variable);
    echo $numbers;
?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/xeNUDk

Note that this might not work with more complicated cases such as multiple number groups separated by other characters. If you need support for that, comment with more details and I'll see what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use preg_replace

```
$variable = "something123";

echo preg_replace('/[^\d]/','', $variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are too fast and too simple in this case.

```
implode(array_intersect(str_split($variable), range(0,9)));
```

Comment: Hilarious! You made my day :D